# Apply and save buttons won't work on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

So I have a test on Jenkins running but when I try to configure that job I can't save or apply changes. It simply does nothing.

I checked the console and the following message appears: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

I am using a Jenkins from a friend and I run a command in the console to put me in the same network as him so I can use that Jenkins.

Does anyone have any idea why can't I save changes to a job ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was update the Jenkins and all plugins to the latest version.